# Ansible: EC2 provisioning and Iterations

Tags: jinja2, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to start a bunch of EC2 instances, then install something on them based on the IP given by AWS. With only one EC2, I can add the host and proceed without any issue,but when I chain them using with_dict, I can't achieve it anymore...

The following runs as I want, but I can't understand how to deal with the registered variable ec2_infos I got from the provisioning...

```
- name: Create Test EC2 instances
      ec2:
        group: default
        image: ami-40d28157
        instance_type: '{{item.value.type}}'
        instance_tags:
          Name: "{{ tag+'-'+item.value.name }}"
        key_name: privatekey
        region: us-west-1
        vpc_subnet_id: subnet-REDACTD
        wait: yes
      with_dict: '{{ec2_stack}}'
      register: ec2_infos
```

With a dictionary like

```
ec2_stack:
    serv1:
        type: t2.micro
        name: server1
    serv2:
        type: t2.small
        name: server2
```

ec2_infos is structures like:

```
"ec2_infos": {
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "instance_ids": [
                "i-0fewq09812ddq6"
            ],
            "instances": [
                {
                    "ami_launch_index": "0",
                    "architecture": "x86_64",
                    "block_device_mapping": {
                        "/dev/sda1": {
                            "delete_on_termination": true,
                            "status": "attached",
                            "volume_id": "vol-0987654"
                        }
                    },
                    "dns_name": "",
                    "ebs_optimized": false,
                    "groups": {
                        "sg-qdwdww": "default"
                    },
                    "hypervisor": "xen",
                    "id": "i-083665656521dwq6",
                    "image_id": "ami-40d28157", 
                    "launch_time": "2016-11-24T20:38:53.000Z",
                    "placement": "us-west-1d",
                    "private_ip": "x.x.x.x",
                    "public_dns_name": "",
                    "public_ip": null,
                    "ramdisk": null,
                    "region": "us-east-1",
                    "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1",
                    "root_device_type": "ebs",
                    "state": "running",
                    "state_code": 16,
                    "tags": {
                        "Name": "server1",
                        "Team": "blah"
                    },
                    "tenancy": "default","tenancy": "default", 
                    "virtualization_type": "hvm"
                }
            ], 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "assign_public_ip": false,
                    "exact_count": null, 
                    "group": [
                        "default"
                    ], 
                    "group_id": null, 
                    "id": null, 
                    "image": "ami-40d28157", 
                    "instance_ids": null, 
                    "instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior": null, 
                    "instance_profile_name": null, 
                    "instance_tags": {
                        "Name": "server1", 
                        "Team": "blah"
                    }, 
                    "instance_type": "t2.micro", 
                    "kernel": null, 
                    "volumes": null, 
                    "vpc_subnet_id": "subnet-abcdfed", 
                    "wait": true, 
                    "wait_timeout": "300", 
                    "zone": null
                }, 
                "module_name": "ec2"
            }, 
            "item": {
                "key": "serv1", 
                "value": {
                    "name": "server1", 
                    "type": "t2.micro"
                }
            }, 
            "tagged_instances": []
        }, 
        {
            "_ansible_item_result": true, 
            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
            "_ansible_parsed": true, 
            "changed": true, 
            "instance_ids": [
                "i-0971278624334fd"
            ], 
            "instances": [
                {
                    "ami_launch_index": "0", 
                    "architecture": "x86_64", 
                    "block_device_mapping": {
                        "/dev/sda1": {
                            "delete_on_termination": true, 
                            "status": "attached", 
                            "volume_id": "vol-9999999"
                        }
                    }, 
                    "dns_name": "", 
                    "ebs_optimized": false, 
                    "groups": {
                        "sg-redactd": "default"
                    }, 
                    "launch_time": "2016-11-24T20:39:21.000Z", 
                    "private_ip": "y.y.y.y", 
                    "public_dns_name": "", 
                    "public_ip": null, 
                    "ramdisk": null, 
                    "state": "running", 
                    "state_code": 16, 
                    "tags": {
                        "Name": "serv2", 
                        "Team": "blah"
                    }, 
                    "tenancy": "default", 
                    "virtualization_type": "hvm"
                }
            ], 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "assign_public_ip": false, 

                    "wait_timeout": "300", 
                    "zone": null
                }, 
                "module_name": "ec2"
            }, 
            "item": {
                "key": "server2", 
                "value": {
                    "name": "serv2", 
                    "type": "t2.small"
                }
            }, 
            "tagged_instances": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried with_items and with_subelements in different ways, but I can't manage to get every IPs of the new EC2. I don't even need to sort them just extract them from the instances part and feed them to add_host so I can proceed.

Anybody knows a clean way to do so, or would be kind enough to explain to me how to deal with a registered variable after a loop properly ?

Comment: I can't answer without exact `ec2_infos` format, but you should start with `ec2_infos.results | map(attribute='instances') | sum(start=[])` and `map` for `private_ip` depending on exact object format.

Comment: Thank you, that works ! Would you mine posting it as an answer so I can accept it ? Or should I do it quoting your comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

```
ec2_infos.results | map(attribute='instances') | sum(start=[]) | map(attribute='private_ip') | list
```